# How do I align tasks to the left margin?

Tags: alignment, tasks

I've managed to align it by arbitrarily adjusting the values of "column-sep and item-indent" (the values I used are commented out in the code) but is there another more effective way to do it?
I show the photo of what I had at the beginning when it was misaligned.
[image]

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=4.5cm, right=4.5cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-family,per-mode = symbol}
\spanishdecimal{.} %Para forzar el punto decimal

\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{chemmacros}


\usepackage{tasks}



\title{E34}
\author{Ing. Luque }
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Enunciado}

\LARGE
De las siguientes especies todas son isoelectrónicas menos una. Indique cuál es:
\begin{center}
\ch{O\mch[2]}, \ch{F\mch{}}, Ne, Na, \ch{Mg\pch[2]}
\end{center}
PA\,(uma): O\,=\,8; F\,=\,9; Ne\,=\,10, Na\,=\,11; Mg\,=\,12
\bigskip
\bigskip
\medskip
\spacing{0.5}

\begin{tasks}[label=\Alph*), label-offset =.7em](3)
%column-sep=1em, item-indent=1.4em,
    \task \ch{O\mch[2]}
    \task \ch{Mg\pch[2]}
    \task \ch{F\mch{}}\newline
    \task Ne
    \task []
    \task Na
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately your example is not complete and therefore does not compile. However, have you seen an tried out the options from section 4 of the `tasks` manual, e.g., something like `item-indent=1.4em`?

Answer (score 3):

See page 7 and 8 of [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tasks). It's just a matter of setting correct numbers for `label-width`, `label-offset`, and `item-offset`. You probably need to set `label-align` to `left` as well as a different length for `column-sep` to avoid overlapping subsequent items. Here's a figure from the [manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tasks)

[image]

These settings should give you something close to your expected outcome

```latex
\begin{tasks}[
    label=\Alph*),
    label-align=left,
    item-indent=2em,   % item-indent = label-width + label-offset 
    label-width=1.6em, label-offset=0.4em,
    column-sep=0.75em,
    % debug, % use this to check layout
  ](3)
  % ...
\end{tasks}
```

[image]